# Print a define item of a list that matches another list

Tags: python, list

I have two lists. One has the header and another has the detail. I put a number before each item to help me know which detail belongs to the header. I want to print the header and then the details. How can I do that?

In this example I just want to print the words, not the numbers (index)

My code:

```
header=  ['1', 'header1', '2', 'header2', '3', 'header3', 4, 'header4']
detail= ['1', 'detailA', '1', 'detailB', '2', 'detailA', '3', 'detailA', '4', 'detailA']


for item1 in header:
    index=item1
    i+=i
    print "Header: ", header[i*2-1]
    for item2 in detail:
        j+=1
        print j
        if item1==item2:
            print "Detail:\n"
            print "     ", detail[j*2-1]
```

Comment: Why can't you have a dictionary of header and details?

Comment: I already save the values in list...the values come from other process. Also haven't work with dictionaries.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably create a dictionary here:

```
In [5]: header=  ['1', 'header1', '2', 'header2', '3', 'header3', 4, 'header4']
In [6]: detail= ['1', 'detailA', '1', 'detailB', '2', 'detailA', '3', 'detailA', '4', 'detailA']

In [7]: it=iter(header)                                                        
In [8]: dic={}             #or use collections.defaultdict(list)
                           #to preserve order use collections.OrderedDict()

In [9]: for ind in it:                                                                   
    head=next(it)
    indexes=[i for i,x in enumerate(detail) if x==ind]
    for index in indexes:
        dic.setdefault(head,[]).append(detail[index+1])
   ...:         

In [10]: dic
Out[10]: 
{'header1': ['detailA', 'detailB'],
 'header2': ['detailA'],
 'header3': ['detailA']}
```

Comment: Better variable names may be in order.

Comment: Thank you Ashwini. The numbers 5,6,7,8,9,10 after the INs are the number of items? or just a indicator?

Comment: @netfreak just indicators, similar to `>>>` of normal python shell.

Comment: If the list grow, how can I print them? I see that you write them down again.

Comment: Can any one help me with the idea of the list? please. If I use dictionary I have to change my code. Have no more time.

Answer (score 0):

If the lists come from a third party, then you can transform them into something more usable:

```
header=  ['1', 'header1', '2', 'header2', '3', 'header3', '4', 'header4']
detail= ['1', 'detailA', '1', 'detailB', '2', 'detailA', '3', 'detailA', '4', 'detailA']

header = [ (header [i], header [i + 1] ) for i in range (0, len (header), 2) ]
detail = [ (detail [i], detail [i + 1] ) for i in range (0, len (detail), 2) ]

for k, v in header:
    print ('Header: {}'.format (v) )
    print ('Details:')
    print ('\n'.join (dv for dk, dv in detail if dk == k) )
    print ()
```

I changed in the header list `4` to `'4'`. I don't use dictionaries in order to maintain the order of the headers.